# Get Anchor tag class/id from table jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, anchor

I have a table like this
I need to get the anchor tag value(class or id) from the table.
In other words, how to get the anchor tag value using jQuery

```
        <table class="kimztableclass" id="kimztableid">
        <tr>
        <a class="kimzanchorclass" id="kimzanchorid" >Kimz Value</a>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

I need something like this

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.mytableanchortagclass').editable({
            .........do my coding stuff.................
            }
        }
        });
        });
```

In short - I need to get the anchor tag id/name inorder to proceed with my jQuery stuff.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: try `$('a').attr('id')`

Comment: oops !!! sorry. I missed, but got the answer for my question from anoop.. thanks all .. again sorry

Comment: could someone please help me with this question which i have asked in SOF - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351116/bootstrap-pagination-an-inline-implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

**For getting class name**

```
$(".kimztableclass a").attr("class");
```

**For getting Id**

```
$(".kimztableclass a").attr("id");
```

**For getting text**

```
$(".kimztableclass a").text();
```

Comment: that is done anoop.. thanks again. :) you are my time-saver

Comment: anoob - could you please help me with this question which i have asked in SOF - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351116/bootstrap-pagination-an-inline-implementation

Answer (score 1):

use attr() method

```
$('.mytableanchortagclass tr').find('a').attr('id')
```

Comment: thanks bro, could you please help me with this question which i have asked in SOF - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351116/bootstrap-pagination-an-inline-implementation

Answer (score 0):

This will return all anchor tag with class `kimzanchorclass`:

```
$('a.kimzanchorclass').attr('id');
```